# Build dynamic menu using ng-zorro

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to dynamically build a menu using the ng-zorro library. The problem is that I want to render nested submenus using recursive ng-template, and I'm getting the error when trying to use the nz-submenu directive inside ng-template.
The error is `NullInjectorError: No provider for MenuService!`
Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ojfbuo-ktddi3?file=src/app/app.component.ts.

Has anybody encountered such a problem and was able to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to move ngTemplate inside the first ngContainer that menu exist
[fixed stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ojfbuo-7rkgsn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-menu-horizontal',
  template: `
    <ul nz-menu nzMode="inline">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let menu of menus">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context: { menu: menu }"></ng-container>
      <ng-template #recursiveListTmpl let-menu="menu">
        <li
            *ngIf="menu.children && menu.children.length > 0"
            nz-submenu
        >
          {{menu.title}} 
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context: { menu: menu.children }"></ng-container>
        </li>
    </ng-template>
    <li *ngIf="!menu.children || menu.children.length==0" nz-menu-item>
      {{menu.title}}
    </li>
      </ng-container>
  </ul>
  `,
})
export class NzDemoMenuHorizontalComponent {
  menus = [
    { title: 'test', children: [] },
    {
      title: 'with children',
      children: [
        { title: 'child', children: [{ title: 'child 2', children: [] }] },
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```